# Как равномерно отрисовать данные между тремя блоками?

Tags: javascript

Нужно создавать три блока в которых будут отрисовываться чекбоксы.

Есть массив с данными их нужно как то равномерно отрисовать между тремя блоками.

т.е если в массиве будет всего 3 элемента то каждый чекбокс окажется в каждом блоке контейнере

```js
var widgetSettings = [
            {   id: 'inlineCheckbox1',
                value:'option1',
                text: 'Статистика за период',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-statistic',
                    StatusChecked: true
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox2',
                value:'option2',
                text: 'Агентское вознаграждение',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-statistic',
                    StatusChecked: true
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox3',
                value:'option3',
                text: 'Экономия',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-statistic',
                    StatusChecked: true
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox4',
                value:'option4',
                text: 'Заканчивается аннуляция без штрафа',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-applications',
                    StatusChecked: true
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox5',
                value:'option5',
                text: 'Скоро заезд',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-applications',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox6',
                value:'option6',
                text: 'Комментарии',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-applications',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox7',
                value:'option7',
                text: 'Чат агентов',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-applications',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox8',
                value:'option8',
                text: 'Поиск отелей',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-applications',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox9',
                value:'option9',
                text: 'Время и дата',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-applications',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox10',
                value:'option10',
                text: 'Погода',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-applications',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox11',
                value:'option11',
                text: 'Календарь заявок',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-applications',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox12',
                value:'option12',
                text: 'Ваши бонусы',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-statistic',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox13',
                value:'option13',
                text: 'Карта заказов',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-statistic',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox14',
                value:'option14',
                text: 'Игра "Bronevik"',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-statistic',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox15',
                value:'option15',
                text: 'Наши публикации Instagram',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-statistic',
                    StatusChecked: false
                }
            },{
                id: 'inlineCheckbox16',
                value:'option16',
                text: 'Наши публикации Facebook',
                type: {
                    name: 'widget-statistic',
                    StatusChecked: true
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: как идет распределение? в начале в первой строке 1,2,3 потом во второй 4,5,6 и т.д  или в первом столбце первые N во втором вторые и третьем оставшиеся?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в первом столбце первые N во втором вторые и третьем оставшиеся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При длине не делящейся на 3 остаются лишние элементы, куда их девать можете решить сами, я их просто закинул в последний блок.

```js
var blockCount = 3;
var sliceStep = parseInt(widgetSettings.length /blockCount)
var countSlice = widgetSettings.length / Math.ceil(sliceStep);
  
for(var i = 1; i <= countSlice; i++){
    (function(i){
  var sliceFrom = (i-1)*sliceStep; 
  if(i == blockCount){
   console.log(widgetSettings.slice(sliceFrom, widgetSettings.length))
  } else {
   console.log(widgetSettings.slice(sliceFrom, sliceFrom+sliceStep))
  }
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: неа. при 17 элементах получится 5-5-7, а скорее всего должно быть 6-6-5 ну или 5-6-6..... при 18 получается вообще 6-6 без третьего столбца внезапно)  Вообще в данной задаче (если я конечно не загоняюсь) необходимо  у самого ТС узнать, при различных комбинациях количества элементов и количества столбцов - какие будут приемлемые по его мнению варианты....тот же 5-5-7 является для него равномерным или нет и т.д. Потому что от этого зависит нужно ли высчитывать всякие остатки и применять некие вычисления или нет

Comment: да, i <= надо было, поправил спасибо за поправку.
А по поводу дальнейшего распределения элементов, человек ведь должен подумать и сам немного ))) развернуть дальнейшую обработку в зависимости от потребностей очень легко в любую сторону.

Comment: @KamilMagomedov да спасибо, мне хватит только реализации чтоб понять , остальное уже мелочи с какой стороны сделать)
Одно но, при 4 элементах цикл проходит еще раз по последнему эл и выдает его т.е в консоли у нас 4 массива)